# Python regex search and replace all ocurrences

Tags: python, regex, django

I hope you can help me with this. I'm writing a code in python to replace all occurrences on a string that includes: @[username](user: id)

I tried with the following code, but only works if my string is something like this:

```
mystring = '@[otheruser](id: 100)' and match and replace it's ok. But if I pass a string like this:

mystring = 'He is @[otheruser](id: 100) and he is @[newuser](id: 20)' doesn't work, nothing gets replaced.
```

Code:

```
import re

mystring = 'He is @[otheruser](id: 100) and he is @[newuser](id: 20)'

regex = re.compile(r'^@\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]\((id: ([0-9]+))\)', re.S)
iter = re.finditer(regex, mystring)

    for result in iter:
        match = result.group()
        g1 = result.group(1)
        g2 = result.group(2)
        g3 = result.group(3)

        print(match) # full match
        print(g1) # otheruser
        print(g2) # id: number_id
        print(g3)  # number_id

        parsed_string = re.sub(p, '<a href="view/'+g3+'">@'+g1+'</a>' , mystring)
```

**Output should be something like:**

```
He is <a href="view/100">@otheruser</a> and he is <a href="view/20">@newuser</a> doesn't work, nothing gets replaced.
```

Comment: this for markdown syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs for the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) method say:

> Backreferences, such as \6, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

So, change to this:

```
import re

mystring = 'He is @[otheruser](id: 100) and he is @[newuser](id: 20)'
my_re = r'@\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\]\((id: ([0-9]+))\)'  # note the missing ^ at start

regex = re.compile(my_re, re.S)
iter = re.finditer(regex, mystring)

for result in iter:
    match = result.group()
    g1 = result.group(1)
    g2 = result.group(2)
    g3 = result.group(3)

    print(match) # full match
    print(g1) # otheruser
    print(g2) # id: number_id
    print(g3)  # number_id

    # we make use of \1 to match the first matched group (which is the number_id 
    # and \3 which is the username
    parsed_string = re.sub(my_re, 
                           r'<a href="view/\3">@\1</a>', 
                           mystring)
    print(parsed_string)
    # prints
    # He is <a href="view/100">@otheruser</a> and he is <a href="view/20">@newuser</a>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help, works great, I think I misunderstood the use of ^

Comment: @ElrosRomeo. If my answer helped you to solve your issue, please accept it. It's a good practice in StackOverflow. Also, if you really liked it, upvote it too :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code does but substituting the string in python using re is as simple as this:

```
import re

mystring = 'He is @[otheruser](id: 100) and he is @[newuser](id: 20)'
regex = re.compile(r'@\[(\w+)\]\(id\:\s(\d+)\)', re.I)
r_p = r'<a href="view/\2">@\1</a>'
print(regex.sub(p, mystring))
```

Please see that I removed `^` (caret) as it denotes starting of the string which is not the case in your case.
https://regex101.com/r/fUztdt/1

Comment: Most of the functions under `re` work with both string or already compiled pattern object.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your help too.